# Android MessageQueue in Handler sent with unexpected latency

Tags: android, message-queue, message, android-handler, android-handlerthread

I created an architecture with a process `A` communicating to another process `B` through IPC.

`A` runs a sticky service. `B` runs a sticky service.

This `A` service binds to the `B` service.

When bind succeeds,

- for requests from A to B, A creates :

```
mRequestMessenger = new Messenger(service); //service comes from onServiceConnected(..., IBinder service)
```

- for answers from B to A, A creates :

```
//create the handler thread, start it
mResponseHandlerThread = new HandlerThread(mModuleName);
mResponseHandlerThread.start();
    
//Set thread as looper of ResponseHandler
mResponseHandler = new ResponseHandler(mResponseHandlerThread.getLooper()); //ResponseHandler is a Handler
    
//Set ResponseMessenger into messenger to receive callback
mResponseMessenger = new Messenger(mResponseHandler);
```

When `A` receives the responses from `B`, it is treated by first logging the received `android.os.Message` object instance.
This message has the field "when" which shows the delay between message sent from `B` and message received in `A`.

For most of the cases, the value of when is around 0ms or -1ms (negative value due to computation : `createdtime - now`)
For really rare cases, the messages seem stuck until something unlocks the situation.

Logs shows :

> when=-1h49m55s146ms

> when=-1h49m53s904ms

> when=-1h49m54s502ms

....
until all "stuck" messages are well received.

Additionnally, when there are too many stuck messages, it seems that some of them are lost, with a limit of 875 messages.

I can't figure out what could explain this behavior.